# How to exclude 'out of stock' items from the front page?

Tags: magento, product

I'm currently using Magento 1.1.6. My store only sells unique items (shirts with exclusive designs) which means at any one time, only 1 unit is available for each items.

How do I omit those items which are already sold from being displayed in the front page?

BTW, I'm using these code to show products on the front page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list_home_batik.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to System>Configuration>Catalog>Inventory>Stock Options. the dropdown for "Display Out of Stock Products" change to No.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed the file catalog/product/list_home_batik.phtml is based on catalog/product/list.phtml

You can modify the file catalog/product/list_home_batik.phtml by adding

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
```

just after

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

and by adding

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

just before

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If it doesn't work, you should provide the complete file so I can have a look at it.

Comment: the third one should be <?php endif; ?>